# SecurityException when instantiating MongoClient (C# / IIS 8 / Windows Server 2012)

Tags: c#, mongodb, iis

I'm getting a System.Security.SecurityException when trying to create a new MongoClient in C#:

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
```

This is part of a WCF Service hosted in IIS 8.

part of the stack trace:

```
at MongoDB.Driver.PasswordEvidence.TransformFinalBlock(HashAlgorithm hash, SecureString   secureString)
at MongoDB.Driver.PasswordEvidence.GenerateDigest(SecureString secureString)
at MongoDB.Driver.PasswordEvidence..ctor(SecureString password)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCredential.FromComponents(String mechanism, String source, String username, String password)
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(MongoUrl url)
```

Application pool is set to: .NET v4.5 Classic, I've tested with different identities.
I can connect to MongoDB from within a console application on the server.

Comment: Since you have access to the server, you could try to set a higher trust level http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753658(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks, it was actually a 32 bit problem - changing the app pool to support 32 bit applications (for the MongoDB driver) was fixing it.